# Uniformly bounded operator norm on compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

My lecture notes on real analysis prove the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions.

> Theorem: Suppose $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable with
>   uniformly bounded operator norm $ \|df_x\|_{operator} \leq C$ for
>   some $C \geq 0$ and all $x \in U$. Then, for all $a,b$ such that
>   $\bar{ab} \in U$
>
> $\|f(b)-f(a)\| \leq \sqrt{n}C \|b-a\|$.

Here $\bar{ab}$ is the segment between $a$ and $b$ and the operator norm for a linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n, L(x)=Ax$ is defined as

$\|L\|:=\|A\|:=sup\{\|L(x)\|=\|Ax\| : \|x\| \leq 1\}$.

After that the author mentions this:

> Note that over compact subsets of U, some bound on the operator norm
>   is automatic.

$U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

However, I don't understand why this is true. When I read compact set, then I immediately think of the fact that continuous functions are uniformly continuous and that it's range is closed and bounded. Can anyone explain why the statement is true?

Any help is appreciated since I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable: over any compact subset of $U$, the function $N(x) = \|df_x\|$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the operator norm) is continuous and therefore bounded.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the operator norm is also bounded by this bound as it is the supremum, correct? I actually thought this was meant to be a uniform bound as in the theorem, but I guess I misinterpreted the statement.

Comment: I don't see how that continuity follows from anything that's given in the question...

Comment: Well, we are working with finite dimensional vector spaces, so linear maps are continuous and the norm is also continuous. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Yes, if $K \subset U$, then the same upper bound $C$ applies. Note that any upper bound of a continuous function over a compact set is automatically a uniform bound.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy I incorrectly assumed that the map $df_U \to \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ is continuous

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You're right; I accidentally assumed that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I am lost now. $df_x$ is a linear map with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it is a bounded operator and therefore continuous. Not sure why you say you have incorrectly assume that $df_x$ is continuous.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom _If_ the OP is telling us the whole truth about what it says in the book it seems likely the author made the same assumption.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Yes, each $df_x$ is a linear map. For each fixed $x$, $df_x$ is a continuous map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$. That says that for each $x$ the norm of $df_x$ is finite. It doesn't say that this norm is _bounded_. That would follow if we knew that the map $x\mapsto df_x$ was continuous.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy I meant the map $df:U \to \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ defined by $x \mapsto df_x$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah, now I understand. Yes, in fact we do not know this. Maybe the author simply meant that for a fixed $x$ the function $h \to df_x(h)$ is bounded and therefore has a bounded operator norm. This works for all $x$, from that we cannot say if there is a bound that is uniform for all $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If you edit your answer such that it is clear that we need to assume continuity of $x \to df_x$, then I can accept it. It is still sufficent for what I want to achieve. Would also be good to make it clear that the norm is actually the operator norm.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Updated my post accordingly

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually, got one more question. Shouldn't we say that $f$ is continuously differentiable implies that the function $df : x \to df_x$ is continuous and therefore its range is bounded. This means that$\|dfx\|_{operator}<K$ for some $K≥0$ since the function maps into the space of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with the operator norm. So sum up we actually do not need define the function $N(x)$ that maps $x$ onto the norm of $df_x$ to prove this. Is that correct?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy That's correct. I figured that the explanation with $N$ might be a bit more intuitive, however, since it doesn't require thinking about compact sets in $\Bbb R^{n \times m}$, but yours is more to the point.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah, it really doesn't matter. Thanks for coming back on this. We actually do not have to think about compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. It suffices to know that a continuous function on a compact set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ has a compact range and compact sets are closed and bounded in any metric space.